# Solr merging parent and child fields in block indexing

Tags: solr

In solr 4.5, block indexing is introduced. If someone has used it successfully, can anyone tell how to query on child documents and get result as parent-child merged documents. Either  tree structure or normal merged child documents with duplicate fields